# Solve the system of PDEs.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

**Finite difference schemes and Partial differential equations, Strikwerda, 2ed, p.22**

> $$u_t+\frac 1 3(t-2)u_x + \frac 2 3 (t+1) w_x +\frac 1 3 u = 0$$ $$w_t
> + \frac 1 3 (t+1)u_x + \frac 1 3 (2t-1) w_x - \frac 1 3 w =0 $$ for $x \in [-3,3], t \in [0,2]$. The initial values are $u(0,x)=\max(0,1-|x|), w(0,x)=\max(0,1-2|x|)$ and boundary values are $u=0$ and $w_x=0$. Solve the system in the form given; do not attempt to diagonalize it.

I numerically solved the problem using Lax-Friedrichs scheme, and I want to compare my numerical solution with the analytic solution. So how can I solve the problem? Also is it impossible to solve it by diagonalization? (I don't know why the last sentence in the problem is given.)

Comment: Are you sure that there is no sign mistake in $+\frac13 u $ or in $-\frac13 w$ ?